# Как получить свойство из результатов запроса php

Tags: php, foreach

Мне нужно получить свойство объекта из результатов запроса к базе. Вот запрос:

```
class Sales {
    public static function get_one_sales ($number_n)
    {
        $db = new DB;
        return $db->query("SELECT * FROM `sale` WHERE `number`='$number_n'", "Sales");
    }
}
```

Вот обращение

```
$tt = Sales::get_one_sales($number_n);
foreach($tt as $rows_sale):
    $rows_sale->contragent_id;
endforeach;
```

Через цикл все работает норм, но я так думаю, что использовать `foreach` для вывода только одного значения, как минимум глупо и не по фэн-шую. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, если не трудно, направьте на путь истинный.

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что использовать цикл для массива это глупо? Куда хуже подставлять переменную в запрос, используйте PDO и подготовку запроса для этих целей. А цикл для того места, в котором может прийти массив, не глупо. Ну или добавьте в запрос `LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

Если результатом `Sales::get_one_sales($number_n)` будет массив со строками (а скорее всего одна строка), тогда можно попробовать так:

```
$tt = Sales::get_one_sales($number_n);
$tt[0]->contragent_id;
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное RaZik. Спасли)))